# MS PowerQuery finding differences between columns and returning them in another columns

Tags: powerquery

I need to find out differences between columns were my students are putting their answers and i want to check those answers against the right answers using PowerQuery.

example:

[image: example]

Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Please provide some indication how any of the columns are related to each other. 1st wrong answer is based on what comparisons of columns? 2nd wrong answer?

Comment: thank you. i need to check the 3 students answer against the 2 right answers. and also if student put another answer which is not in the right answers it should be also considered as wrong answer. im sorry i know its confusing and complicated.

Comment: i guess i made mistake in the screenshot :( result should be fried chicken, chocolate muffin and apple pie

Comment: I have no idea how apple pie plays into this. Please edit your question to show what you are wanting